# Can't process MySQL FULL JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to `FULL JOIN` following two tables

Table 1: Persons

```
P_Id      Name            
 1         A        
 2         B       
 3         C
 4         D
 5         E
```

Table 2: Invoice

```
  Id       P_Id            
 111        3        
 112        3       
 113        1
 114        1
 115       15
```

I used this query :

```
SELECT Persons.Name, Persons.P_Id, Invoice.Id
FROM Persons
FULL JOIN Invoice
ON Persons.P_Id=Invoice.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.Name
```

But this generates an error

> *Unknown column 'Persons.Name' in 'Field list'*

MySQL server version is 5.5.19 and I used command line client in Microsoft Windows7

INNER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN worked for me but I can't perform FULL JOIN. What is the error please tell me I'm still a student. How can I perform FULL JOIN here ?

Thank You!

Comment: Have a look here http://explainextended.com/2009/04/06/emulating-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Comment: Solved by using UNION of LEFT JOIN and the RIGHT JOIN of both tables
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in order to simulate `FULL JOIN` in mysql, you need to `UNION` the result of Right Join and Left Join from both tables

```
SELECT  Persons.Name, Persons.P_Id, Invoice.Id
FROM    Persons
        LEFT JOIN Invoice
            ON Persons.P_Id=Invoice.P_Id
UNION
SELECT  Persons.Name, Persons.P_Id, Invoice.Id
FROM    Invoice
        LEFT JOIN Persons
            ON Persons.P_Id=Invoice.P_Id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99b77/3)

Comment: @LolCoder nope, i used to use all `LEFT` join rather the left and right join. see the interchanging of columns. `:D`