# When querying certain fields, only those users with data in every field are returned

Tags: sql, wordpress

I wish to show a line-item for each user, regardless of whether they have a value for wpcf-dc-license-number, wpcf-dc-license-expiration, etc.

Currently my results only display user line-items for those users who have all the fields fulfilled.

```
SELECT lx_usermeta.meta_value AS dc_license_number,
lx_usermeta2.meta_value AS dc_license_expiration,
lx_usermeta3.meta_value AS md_license_number,
lx_usermeta4.meta_value AS md_license_expiration,
lx_usermeta5.meta_value AS va_license_number,
lx_usermeta6.meta_value AS va_license_expiration,
lx_usermeta7.meta_value AS first_name,
lx_usermeta8.meta_value AS last_name,
lx_usermeta9.meta_value AS ltx_company

FROM lx_usermeta
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta2 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta2.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta3 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta3.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta4 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta4.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta5 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta5.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta6 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta6.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta7 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta7.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta8 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta8.user_id
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta9 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta9.user_id

WHERE lx_usermeta.meta_key = "wpcf-dc-license-number"
AND lx_usermeta2.meta_key = "wpcf-dc-license-expiration"
AND lx_usermeta3.meta_key = "wpcf-maryland-license-number"
AND lx_usermeta4.meta_key = "wpcf-maryland-license-expiration"
AND lx_usermeta5.meta_key = "wpcf-virginia-license-number" 
AND lx_usermeta6.meta_key = "wpcf-virginia-license-expiration"
AND lx_usermeta7.meta_key = "first_name"
AND lx_usermeta8.meta_key = "last_name"
AND lx_usermeta9.meta_key = "wpcf-ltx-company"
```

I have tried changing the JOIN to LEFT JOIN, FULL JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN, placing UNION between the JOIN statements, but I'm not having any luck finding a way to have these fields joined without the exclusive requirement of having all the wpcf fields filled in.

Thank you for your help!

UPDATE:
I have tested this code:

```
SELECT lx_usermeta.meta_value AS first_name, lx_usermeta2.meta_value AS last_name
FROM lx_usermeta
JOIN lx_usermeta lx_usermeta2 ON lx_usermeta.user_id = lx_usermeta2.user_id
WHERE lx_usermeta.meta_key =  "first_name"
AND lx_usermeta2.meta_key =  "last_name"
```

This will show all users one after another, even if they have only one or even neither of first_name or last_name.

What could possibly be affecting the wpcf-* fields (custom fields) so that when I use the same syntax with them, I only receive results in which there is data for all the wpcf-fields?

Comment: use left join instead of join.

Comment: Just replaced all the JOIN with LEFT JOIN and got the same results.

OK! I tried ensuring another user had all the fields I'm pulling from filled out, like the one user that was showing up. Now those two show up. So my problem is I need to make my script not care if every field that is listed is actually filled in for each user, and show them anyway.

Comment: I feel like I am looking for FULL JOIN or outer FULL OUTER JOIN but i see my syntax for FULL not getting colored in, and a syntax error when i run it.

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598221/cant-process-mysql-full-join-query

This is helpful and relevant to my issue so I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both your suggestion fubar, as well as this:

```
SELECT

    um.meta_value AS dc_license_number,

    um2.meta_value AS dc_license_expiration,

    um3.meta_value AS md_license_number,

    um4.meta_value AS md_license_expiration,

    um5.meta_value AS va_license_number,

    um6.meta_value AS va_license_expiration,

    um7.meta_value AS first_name,

    um8.meta_value AS last_name,

    um9.meta_value AS ltx_company

FROM

    lx_usermeta um

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um2 ON um.user_id = um2.user_id AND 'wpcf-dc-license-expiration' = um2.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um3 ON um.user_id = um3.user_id AND 'wpcf-maryland-license-number' = um3.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um4 ON um.user_id = um4.user_id AND 'wpcf-maryland-license-expiration' = um4.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um5 ON um.user_id = um5.user_id AND 'wpcf-virginia-license-number' = um5.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um6 ON um.user_id = um6.user_id AND 'wpcf-virginia-license-expiration' = um6.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um7 ON um.user_id = um7.user_id AND 'first_name' = um7.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um8 ON um.user_id = um8.user_id AND 'last_name' = um8.meta_key

LEFT JOIN lx_usermeta um9 ON um.user_id = um9.user_id AND 'wpcf-ltx-company' = um9.meta_key

WHERE

    um.meta_key = 'wpcf-dc-license-number';
```

I am getting some results now but only for my three dummy users (one blank company name, two Northwinds) and Cushman Wakefield users.

[here you can see only cushman and the dummies returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoSOX.png)

[here you can see in wordpress, users of other companies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1oxM.png)

These users were imported from different companies and different sheets, and the data combined/updated appropriately for each user for each company. I'm just saying, Cushman Wakefield should not be unique in any way to the others.

Thanks for your help!